# Spread class functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to spread the functions of a class into another object? As a contrived example:

```
class FooBar {
    private service: MyService;

    constructor(svc: MyService) {
       this.service = svc;
    }

    public foo(): string {
        return "foo";
    }

    public bar(): string {
        return "bar"
    }

    public fooBar(): string {
        return "foobar"
    }
}

let obj = new FooBar();

export default {
    ...obj
};
```

I would want the exported object to contain all the methods of the class `FooBar` but not the private property `service`. However, those methods are placed on the prototype object when compiled to javascript so they are not included in the spread operation and the private property is included on the object to it is in the resulting object.

I know I can do this:

```
export default {
    foo: obj.foo.bind(obj),
    bar: obj.bar.bind(obj),
    fooBar: obj.fooBar.bind(obj),
};
```

I would like to avoid this if possible as I will have methods from multiple classes to map.

Note: This is to be used for combining GraphQL resolvers into a single object that will be supplied to the `graphql` function.

I am running my app using `ts-node` if that makes any difference.

Comment: Get the `Object.entries` then `Array#filter` them to only keep values that are functions then `Array#reduce` it to an object that contains these entries

Comment: You could get prototype (`Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`) and bind its methods to the `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of problems going on. First, I was targeting `es6` as my output instead of `es5`. Doing that caused there to be no prototype on the compiled object.

Second, just doing the spread caused the private property `service` to be included in the exported object. I ended up writing a helper function as alluded to by @Vivick and @AlekseyL.:

```
function combineResolvers(...resolvers: any[]): any {
    let out: { [key: string]: any } = {}
    resolvers.forEach(resolver => {
        let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(resolver)
        Object.keys(proto)
            .filter(key => {
                return isFunction(resolver[key]);
            }).forEach(key => {
                out[key] = resolver[key].bind(resolver)
            })
    })

    return out
}

function isFunction(functionToCheck: any): boolean {
    return functionToCheck && {}.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}
```

This still has the problem of including any private functions on the resolver classes into the exported object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work; using arrow functions for autobinding the methods and spreading it with Object.assign

```
class FooBar {
  private service: MyService;

  constructor(svc: MyService) {
    this.service = svc;
  }

  public foo = (): string => {
    return "foo";
  }

  public bar = (): string => {
    return "bar";
  }

  public fooBar = (): string => {
    return "foobar";
  }
}

export default { ...Object.assign(new FooBar()) };
```

But maybe you would want to take a look at this before doing that
https://www.charpeni.com/blog/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think